# Getting Error while including a bootstrap Style to my Angular project

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a spinner while the data from database is still loading, loading is assigned as false at the beginning , for that I added the following code to my HTML File

```
<div *ngIf="loading" class="text-center">
  <div class="spinner-border text-warning" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
  Fetching...
</div>
```

and following to the angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"            ],

 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

I have installed bootstrap properly but still I am getting this error-
An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js does not exist.
See "\angular-errors.log" for further details.

And when I go to error logs , I get this-
[error] Error: Script file ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js does not exist.

I navigated to the location and the bootstrap.js file is at the location.
I know it's a small issue but I was unable to load the style without solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I don't know how it happened but I had multiple Script and Styles tags in my angular.json, maybe it's because I updated them more often while solving the error.But it got resolved when I used the correct tags to mention the location of script and style files.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add a ',' (comma) before bootstrap file

Your code:

```
 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

Should be:

```
"scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
```

Comment: Hello, already had it in my original code , must have clicked backspace by mistake, sorry for that , but the problem still persists.